# Forecasting with MA-Model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, moving-average

Am i right in the assumption that you can only do one step ahead forecasts with the MA-Model?

For example in the MA(1)-Model Forecast

```
Y(t+1)=alpha*e(t)+e(t+1)
```

we have e(t) as the real Value Y(t) minus the value of the forecast of Y(t). Now for the next forecast Y(t+2) we need the residual e(t+1). But this residual is only available if we know the real value of the time series Y(t+1) or am i missing something? Is there a way to do a n-step ahead forecast without knowing the real time series Y(t+1) to Y(t+n-1)?

Comment: You can iterate. An $h$-step-ahead forecast from MA(q) model will be equal to the $q$-step-ahead forecast when $h>q$.

Comment: But for the q-step ahead forecast I also need e(t+1), ..., e(t+q-1)? My Problem is, that I don't know how to get those residuals.

Comment: You forecast those, and the forecasts are equal to zero.

Comment: So they disappear and after forecast q the forecast is the mean of the model?

Comment: Not the mean but the MA($q$) forecast.